# AutoIT TCP Protocol

Tags: sockets, tcp, protocols, autoit

Witam.

I'm trying to send in a scripting language AutoIT using the TCP Send to type Hex Socket data.
I do this in the following way:

```
_AutoItObject_StartUp()
Global $oTCP = _Class_TCPClient($ip,$port)
```

Previously, $ip and $port is entered manually.
TCPStartup() is included in _Class_TCPClient.
Class_TCPClient - constructor.

```
$oTCP.Connect()

Local $string = _HexToString(0xBB01C8007F010140)
Local $ret = $oTCP.Send($string)
```

But it does not work.

When you preview frames using Wireshark data field looks quite different.

The target script which is communication protocol for device from company where I'm working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [BinaryToString](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/BinaryToString.htm) function.

Do not forget to use quotes: `BinaryToString("0x...")`

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and in my opinion this is the best option to send this frame.
The problem is whenever i change frame, then it sends the same data.